# Multiline chart with a 2 level nest, conversion from v4 to v5 problem

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I am trying to create this (https://bl.ocks.org/ProQuestionAsker/952a0699278d1bdfda36d4b7175924d3) exact chart but in d3 version 5 and am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Basically am trying to make 4 lines total, there are 2 fruit types and 2 years in the data.

This is how I am making my nest:

```
        var nest = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d){ return d.fruit; })
            .key(function(d){ return d.year; })
            .entries(data);
```

And this is how I am trying to make the paths:

```
var fruits = svg.selectAll(".fruits")
            .data(nest)
            .enter()
            .append("g"); 

        var paths = fruits.selectAll("path")
            .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
            console.log(d)
            .enter()
            .append("path"); 

        paths
            .attr("d", function(d){
                return valueLine(d.values); 
            });
```

I am stuck here because I've tried to reformat this a number of different ways and still no lines are drawn. I think maybe I am just having a conversion from v4 to v5 problem. Thank you in advance for your time.

Here is the link to the codepen project with my code: https://codepen.io/amandaraen/project/editor/DOgwYn#0

Comment: Looks like you line accessor uses a capital when accessing x/y: d.Sales, while your data does not.

Comment: hey thanks for noticing that, I noticed that too since posting and just updated the codepen project, still having no lines being drawn though.

Comment: @AndrewReid do you think you would be willing to take one more look at it? I fixed the capitalization problem. I really appreciate your help

Comment: I will - pre-occupied momentarily though.

Comment: No problem, whenever you can get around to it :)

Comment: Now you get coordinates for every point in the line which is good. The issue is likely with your scales. It looks like you use parseMonth for both numeric months (as in the csv) and short form months (as when setting the scale's domain). But parseMonth only uses `%b - abbreviated month name.`.